# Is there a way to 'catch' mapping validation errors in RestKit programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, restkit

If my mappings have been setup incorrectly then when I call the following method on `RKObjectManager` to get objects:

```
- (void)getObjectsAtPath:(NSString *)path
              parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                 success:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult))success
                 failure:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
```

the following error appears in the logs when the mapping is resolved against the source:

```
2014-01-05 20:49:35.020 xxxx[26224:1807] E restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:335 Validation failed while mapping attribute at key path 'xxxx' to value <xxx: 0xc3d1930> (entity: xxx; id: 0xc3d1970 <x-coredata:///xxxx/tCC01E8C7-B34D-4302-A889-67E21C58275D18> ; data: {
    xxxx = xxxx,
    xxxx = xxxx 
}). Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.)
```

However the success block is called rather than the failure block despite the fact that all mapping operations have failed.

Is there any way in which to determine whether or not these errors have occurred within the success block? As from the point of view of my tests, the operation succeeds but simply has no results returned.

Comment: Your test should verify the returned data...

Comment: Did you check the operation parameter for errors?

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but with an integration test for example, sometimes a GET against a collection could return no results `[]` which would be entirely acceptable, however at the moment this would be indistinguishable from a problem in my complex mappings which worries me a little. Yep - I can see no trace in the operation parameter of any errors.